# Detect design time in NetBeans

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, design-time, matisse

When using the Swing graphical editor in NetBeans is it possible for a custom component to detect that it's design time? E.g.

```
public CustomComponent() {
    initComponents();

    if (!isDesignTime()) {
        someIcon = IconFactory.loadIcon("icons/SomeIcon.png");
    }
}
```

Basically I'm after something like .net's [`Component.DesignMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.component.designmode.aspx)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try:

```
java.beans.Beans.isDesignTime()
```